# Show a set it open but not closed

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A = \{ z : |z| < 1 \} $ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $A$ is open but not closed.

#### Try:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Pick any $z_0 \in A$ and choose $\epsilon = 1 - |z_0| $. We show $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$. This will prove our set is open. Suppose $w \in D(z_0, \epsilon )$. this means that $|w-z_0| < \epsilon$. We must show that $w \in A$. Notice:

$$ |w| =|w - z_0 + z_0| \leq |w-z_0| + |z_0| < \epsilon + |z_0| < 1 - |z_0| + |z_0| = 1$$

and we have our conclusion. Is this a correct solution? Also, I am stuck on trying to show it is not closed. Can someone help me?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, then how is it possible that $\epsilon + |z_0| = 1$?

Comment: Why the downvote....? The reasoning is not perfect, I agree, but that's hardly a reason to downvote the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No, there are some mistakes.**

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Pick any $z_0 \in A$ and choose $\epsilon = 1 - |z_0| $. We show $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$. This will prove our set is open. Suppose $w \in D(z_0, \epsilon )$. this means that $|w-z_0| < \epsilon$. We must show that $w \in A$. Notice:
>
> $$ |w| =|w - z_0 + z_0| \leq |w-z_0| + |z_0| < \epsilon + |z_0| = 1 - |z_0| + |z_0| = 1$$

**I has to be:**

> Let $z_0 \in A$ be given. Pick $\epsilon = 1 - |z_0|$. We show $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$. This will prove our set is open. Suppose $w \in D(z_0, \epsilon )$. this means that $|w-z_0| < \epsilon$. We must show that $w \in A$. Notice:
>
> $$ |w| =|w - z_0 + z_0| \leq |w-z_0| + |z_0| < \epsilon + |z_0| = 1 - |z_0| + |z_0| = 1$$

**Why?**
The (rather: one) definition is:
$A$ ist open $:\Leftrightarrow$
$$\forall z_0 \in A\exists  \epsilon >0:D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$$
So for any **given** $z_0$ you have **then** to **find** some $\epsilon$.

**Show that A is not closed.**
Ony way is to show that $B:=A^C=\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ ist not open.
(The topological defintion of closed is that the complement is open.)
Suppose $B$ is open.
$z_0=1$ is in $B$.
There has so exist some $\epsilon >0$ (w.l.o.g. $\epsilon < 2$) such that $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset B$.
Since $A \ni 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2} = z_0-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A^C$ we have a contradiction.
Therefore $B$ is not open, so $A$ is not closed.

Comment: The reasoning is **not** correct. The OP wrote "let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. [...] Chooose $\epsilon = 1-|z_0|$."

Comment: @5xum Good point. I did just see what I expected to see.:D I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your wording for the proof that $A$ is open is faulty. There are two things you need to fix:

- You first say "let $\epsilon$ be given", and then say "Choose $\epsilon = 1-|z_0|$". The two sentences are in contradiction to each other.
- You then show that $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subseteq A$ with that poorly defined $\epsilon$ and say "we have our conclusion". But the conclusion referenced here is only of the subsets, not that $A$ is open. You need to improve your wording. Preferably, to something like

  > $A$ is open if, for every *something*, **this** is true. Let $x$ be any *something*. Then, [...], therefore, **this** is true for $x$, and because $x$ is arbitrary, it is true for every *something*.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks concerning your proof:

1. Explain at the beginning of the proof what you are trying to prove and why it suffices to show this in order to prove the statement. So, instead of writing

   > We show $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$. This will prove our set is open.

   it is much more better to write

   > By definition, a set $A$ is open iff for any $z_0 \in A$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$. We show that for any $z_0 \in A$ the inclusion $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subset A$ holds for $\epsilon := 1-|z_0|$.
2. As pointed out by several others, the two sentences

   > Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Pick any $z_0 \in A$ and choose $\epsilon = 1-|z_0|$.

   contradict each other. If you had started with the definition of a set being open (as suggested in 1.), then this mistake wouldn't have happened.
3. The idea of your proof is correct.

Depending on your definition of a closed set, there are several ways to prove that $A$ is not closed:

1. Consider the sequence $z_n := 1-\frac{1}{n} \in A$. Is $z_n$ convergent and, if so, is the limit an element of $A$? What does this say about the closedness of $A$?
2. Consider the set $B := A^c = \{z; |z| \geq 1\}$. Then $A$ is closed if and only if $B$ is open. Consider $z_0 := 1$. Does there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $D(z_0,\epsilon) \subseteq B$? Is $B$ open?